# Is there a solid insulator at room temperature that has a dielectric strength slightly less than that of air?

Tags: electricity, material-science, dielectric, insulators

Ideally the material retains its properties after it breaks down with high voltage.

Comment: The dielectric breakdown of a solid polymer insulator generally results in permanent damage (typically carbonization) to its electrical properties.  You can see this if you attempt to retest a material that has broken down at a certain voltage.  It will start conducting at a much lower voltage.

Comment: I have seen enough on the workbench at one time or another. Most have been composites with a fair amount of grime in the mix. There might be some pure materials, but they usually char on arcing across. I have never tried it with clean fireproof ceramics, though those are usually chosen for their high breakdown strength.